# Olympic game scoring

Tags: code-golf, math, statistics

The challenge is to write a golf-code program that, given n positive real numbers from 0 to 10 (format x.y, y only can be 0 or 5: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 … 9.5 and 10), discard the lowest and highest values (only one, even though they are repeated) and shows the average of the remaining, in x.y format (y can be 0 or 5, rounded to closest), similar to some Olympic Games scoring.

Examples:
Input -> Output

6 -> 6

6.5, 9 -> 8

9, 7, 8 -> 8

6, 5, 7, 8, 9 -> 7

5, 6.5, 9, 8, 7 -> 7

6.5, 6.5, 9.5, 8, 7 -> 7

5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5 -> 7.5

Notes: If the input is only two numbers, do not discard any, just average them. If the input is one number, the output is the same.

Clarifying the rounding rule (sorry, little confuse):

x.01 to x.25 round to x.0

x.26 to x.75 round to x.5

x.76 to x.99 round to x+1.0

Comment: How is the second example (6.5, 9 => 8) valid? If you throw out the high and the low, there are no values left to average?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE!

Comment: Are we required to handle invalid test cases, and could we have a test case with non-integer output?

Comment: I'd suggest we do not handle invalid input, the Olympics will have a fixed number of judges greater than two for such an event. (Diving removes the four extremities from seven for example)

Comment: It's not required. and fixed. Thanks

Comment: Ah, we have to special case when given two judge's scores, that's a little odd.

Comment: If lowest or highest value appear more than once, do we discard all or only one?

Comment: @Night2 only 1 - but, yes, this should be clarified (I worked it out from 6.5, 6.5, 9.5, 8, 7 -> 7)

Comment: Are we to use round-half-up rounding - for example `[5, 6, 6, 10, 11, 13]` leads to an average of `8.25`, should we output `8.0` or `8.5`?

Comment: It seems like you're supposed to round half up

Comment: @Jonathan Allan in that case is 8.0

Comment: So the question is now, why - what is the rounding rule?

Comment: I realized it is a bit confuse, let's round them to the nearest, depending of the platform :)

Comment: Please make this clear in the question. Does x.99 round to x.50 then?

Comment: Tried to fix this, thanks :)

Comment: Your example `6.5, 9` disagrees with your spec which indicates that x.75 rounds to x.5.

Comment: Until the rounding is sorted I’ve voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ṢṖḊȯµÆmḤær0H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd057uKPrxPpDWw@35T7cseTwsiIDj/@H2x81rYn8/z9aIdosVifaTM9UxxJIW@qY61iA@DqmIBZYzFQHLAvkmUNVgvlADBGB8M1BfIg4UMxQx9BAxwxoBBDGKsQCAA)

```
    µ           Take
Ṣ               the input sorted,
 Ṗ              without its last
  Ḋ             or first element,
   ȯ            or the unchanged input if that's empty,
     Æm         then calculate the mean,
       Ḥ        double it,
        ær      round it to the nearest multiple of
          0     10^-0 (= 1),
           H    and halve it.
```

A version which rounds halves down, in accordance with the spec at the expense of the second test case:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ṢṖḊȯµÆmḤ_.ĊH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd057uKPrxPpDWw@35T7csSRe70iXx//D7Y@a1kT@/x@tEG0WqxNtpmeqYwmkLXXMdSxAfB1TEAssZqoDlgXyzKEqwXwghohA@OYgPkQcKGaoY2igYwY0AghjFWIB)

The rounding method here is closer to Jonathan Allan's:

```
Ḥ        Double,
 _       subtract
  .      one half,
   Ċ     round up,
    H    and halve.
```

Comment: Just so happens to accidentally [comply with](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4bmi4bmW4biKyK/CtcOGbeG4pMOmcjBI////WzZd) the update to the spec

Comment: @NickKennedy [If I don't round](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd057uKPrxPpDWw@35T7cscTj////0YY6hgY6ZjrmEBgLAA), that case produces 6.8, which should round up to 7 according to the spec since 6.75 < 6.8 ≤ 7.

Comment: sorry one two many 7s. I meant `[1,10,6,7,7,7]`

Comment: Oh, yeah, it does do that one wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 86 bytes

```
\.5
__
\d+
*4*__
O`_+
_+ (.+) _+
$1
O`.
^ *
$.&*__:
(_+):(\1{4})*(\1\1)?_*
$#2$#3*$(.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxDsIwDEV3n8JSA0piyVKgSWgXRkYuEOEiwdCFAbEhzh6cdLD@e9///fysr3uoO3tZauEIIlAeBH70StdFCITQMjlUNEErhht6MLzXxQxWyM22hO/4c16zBHcWfQ8HMxy9sRxrTZA44gQTZjxBwthSPWLvlXNfdNNrvllutrV/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\.5
__
\d+
*4*__
```

Since Retina can't readily handle fractional or zero numbers, each number is represented in unary as 1 more than 4 times the value. The `.5` therefore expands to 2 `_`s, while the `*4*_` applies to the whole number part, and a final `_` is suffixed.

```
O`_+
```

Sort the numbers into order.

```
_+ (.+) _+
$1
```

If there are at least three numbers, discard the first (smallest) and last (largest).

```
O`.
```

Sort the spaces to the start, thus also summing the numbers.

```
^ *
$.&*__:
```

Count the number of spaces and add `_` and a separator. This then represents the number we have to divide by.

```
(_+):(\1{4})*(\1\1)?_*
$#2$#3*$(.5
```

Divide the sum by the number of numbers, allowing for the fact that we're working in multiples of 4 times the original number, so that the integer and decimal portions can be directly extracted. This is a truncating division, but fortunately because we added an extra `_` to each number, the result effectively includes an extra 0.25, thus giving us the rounding we want.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: **This answer has since become invalid.** It was valid for about half a minute after it was posted.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṢḊṖȯƊÆmḤḞH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd3Q93DntxPpjXYfbch/uWPJwxzyP////R5vqKJiBkaEBEBsCsXEsAA)

Comment: `Ḟ` seems to produce the wrong result for `[6.5,9]`.

Comment: @UnrelatedString At the moment I posted this, it was the correct output. Looks like OP has changed the rule now.

Comment: Yes, I made a mess, sorry :(

Comment: As per my comment under Arnauld's post I basically had this algorithm too, so, after getting clarification on the rules, I've posted mine :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Which is the same as Unrelated String's. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <strike>213</strike> <strike>211</strike> <strike>189</strike> 176 bytes

<sup>Edit: -2 bytes because I ended with `;\n}` when I could just end with a `}`, silly mistake.</sup>

<sup>Edit 2: -22 more bytes by reading about general JS golfing tips. I managed to take out parentheses from my nested ternaries in the `r` rounding function, and used bitwise math operations to avoid using `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil`</sup>

<sup>Edit 3: -13 bytes because I was able to replace the `a.length` shortcut function with just direct calls to `a.length` to save 4 bytes. I also moved the g() function directly into the return statement, since it was only used once, which removed the rest of the bytes.</sup>

```javascript
a=>{s=i=>a.splice(i,1)
e=_=>a.reduce((t,i)=>t+=i)/a.length
r=n=>(m=n%1,m<0.75?m>0.25?~~(n)+0.5:~~(n):n%1?-~n:n)
return a.length>2?r((a.sort((x,y)=>x-y),s(0),s(-1),e())):r(e())}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3NCsIwEITvfQovwi6msRXiT3HTBxGRUKNG2lSSKIrYV6@J4OWbYRhmruqhfOPMLeSP9XiiUZF8ezIkFfe31jQaDCsx03RIkdPHe4wgMIMkw4wMzhVvtT2HS@bIkoSO7LRk3bbgK1F3suALUQ8DWJwVXFQ/V8VGnQ@2spg5He7OTv4jclE7gPjduwDwZK9488xfyDwUCXmJTAMiVg6Sfsamt75vNW/7M5xgJ9hkySNWCeuEDRd7xPEL)

I'm sure it can be improved as I'm fairly new, but it was fun to solve this one. I believe the main things that could be improved are my rounding logic/methods, and the fact that the main function uses a function body (`{ }` and `return`).

There was one thing in the question that was inconsistent with the examples and I wasn't really sure how to handle it. I implemented it so that it's consistent with the examples, but it doesn't exactly reflect the specified rounding rules, here is the example I found to be inconsistent:

6.5, 9 -> 8

You say it should be 8, although the average is 7.75. In the rounding rules you say it has to be at least .76 to go +1. I chose to reflect the examples instead of your rounding rules, so >=0.75 to go +1, and <=0.25 to go -1, between 0.25 and 0.75 (exclusive) for .5. **If the rounding specifications change, my code should be able to adapt without changing the number of bytes, by just changing the numbers in the rounding function `r`**, and maybe the order of the ternary statement depending on the rules.

Slightly ungolfed with explanation (the math operations were changed to bitwise operations and g() is directly in the return statement)

```javascript
a => { // a is the input array
    s = i=>a.splice(i, 1); // shortcut to remove index i for 1 element
    e = _=>a.reduce((t, i) => t += i) / a.length; // get array avg
    g = _=>(a.sort((x,y)=>x-y), s(0), s(-1), e()); // what to execute when > 2: sort, remove 1st/last, get avg
    t = n=>Math.floor(n); // Math.floor shortcut

    // apply olympic rounding to number by checking the value of n%1
    r = n=>(m=n%1,m < 0.75 ? (m > 0.25 ? t(n) + 0.5 : t(n)) : Math.ceil(n));

    // if arr length > 2: round g(), otherwise round e()
    return a.length > 2 ? r(g()) : r(e());
}
```

Comment: I’ve posted a comment on the question about the discrepancy between the example and spec.

Comment: why you do not use l=a.length and everytime you want a length simply call l, here I do not know why you arr using function here

Comment: @chaugiang That would save the value, not a reference to `a.length`, so since I'm using it before & after operations that modify the array, `l` would become invalid as soon as the array is changed. LMK if wrong. It turns out it would actually save me 3 bytes now to just replace this with direct `a.length` calls. When I initially wrote it, I didn't know JS allowed you to use negative numbers for splice, so initially my second splice was `s(l()-1)` instead of just `s(-1)`, and when I had 3 length calls it saved bytes to have this shortcut. Now it's no longer worth it. Thanks, will update!

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>36</s></sup> 35 bytes

```
[:(1r4<.@+&.+:+/%#)}:@}.^:(2<#)@/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600DItMbPQctNX0tK209VWVNWutHGr14qw0jGyUNR30rer@a3JxpSZn5CuYKdgqpCmYQTgWEI6eqY6CJbKIpY6CuY6CBUTIHKJIR8EUIgpXC5EAikIMAEuZo@jRg0uCCCRpPVMUveZgaajC/wA)

Borrowed the double / floor / halve trick for rounding to 0.5 increments from Unrelated String.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
def f(s):z=sorted(s)[1:-1]or s;return round(2*sum(z)/len(z))/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsIwELz7K7ac7MoFQVUCVPmSKIcoWStIYKNdpyogvj3d2FCJ1oe157Eja07n2Af/Po4dOnCaze5ScqCInbyr5e5tWQcC/iSMA3mgMPhOr155OOqLWRzQy2UWq7T@hbR3Z33o2QL1EqVATsOMFCVbeANlOUkWZk5fbwLheoOXac7mLtCxiXk9u3OMUm3DyOKtUqCu1rWFtbEPNP@wsBVq80ttLRSCnzgxZaeQIotWPEdkdRr/9IdaJPXuqxMWT62Um0pqA6H8Hb9P2EqBsPeQfp57uLfz12XGHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṢṖḊȯ⁸ÆmḤ+.ḞH
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of numbers which yields a number.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd057uKPrxPpHjTsOt@U@3LFEW@/hjnke////jzbUUYAgCx0FSyDDIBYA)**

#### How?

```
ṢṖḊȯ⁸ÆmḤ+.ḞH - Link, list of numbers, X
Ṣ            - sort X
 Ṗ           - remove the right-most
  Ḋ          - remove the left-most
    ⁸        - chain's left argument, X
   ȯ         - logical OR (if we have nothing left use X instead)
     Æm      - arithmetic mean
       Ḥ     - double
         .   - literal half
        +    - add
          Ḟ  - floor
           H - halve
```

Comment: @NickKennedy 34/5>6.75

Comment: Sorry meant `1,10,7,7,7,6` where 27/4 = 6.75

Comment: This must be due to floating point limitations since that calculation is being done to yield `6.75` from `Æm`, doubling that gives `13.5` adding a half gives `14` and halving gives `7.0`. Thus this (and the other submission with this issue) is valid, just some answers look wrong! EDIT: if [we multiply up by 100 and use 50 instead of a half](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd057uKPrxPpHjTsOt@U@3LFE29TA4//h6YYGBofbrYDk///RhjqGBjrmYGgWCwA) you can see that the method works in principle

Comment: No the issue is the slightly unconventional rounding in the spec. In fact your answer also gets [1,10,7,6,6,6] wrong (it should be 6 not 6.5), while @UnrelatedString’s original version gets that one right because Python rounds to even (so 12.5 rounds down to 12). As I’ve now pointed out in a comment on the question, one of the examples also violates the rounding spec. Also note that fractions of powers of 2 shouldn’t be an issue for floating point inaccuracy because they have an exact binary representation.

Comment: I feel like the spec is awkward and possibly unintentional. (What does x.251 round to, etc; are the boundaries inclusive, exclusive, or is it up to us?) ...and then there is the comment "I realized it is a bit confuse, let's round them to the nearest, depending of the platform". Maybe we should VTC as unclear?

Comment: yes agree VTC for now

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
o{bṀk|}⟨+/l⟩×₄<÷₂/₂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcL//OqkhzsbsmtqH81foa2f82j@ysPTHzW12Bze/qipSR@I//@PVog2i9WJNtMz1bEE0pY65joWIL6OKYgFFjPVAcsCeeZQlWA@EENEIHxzEB8iHqsQCwA)

And I thought the rounding was awkward in Jelly!

Comment: This is incorrect for `[1,10,7,7,7,6]`; 27/4 = 6.75 which should round to 6.5 according to spec.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 203 bytes

```swift
func a(b:[Double])->Void{var r=0.0,h=0.0,l=11.0
b.forEach{(c)in h=c>h ?c:h;l=c<l ?c:l;r+=c}
var d=Double(b.count)
r=d>2 ?(r-h-l)/(d-2.0):r/d
d=Double(Int(r))
r=r-d<=0.25 ?d:r-d<=0.75 ?d+0.5:d+1
print(r)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xCsIwGIT3PEXGhJo0LYqQNu2igy/gIg5NYkkgpPLb6lD67NVWcTnu4OPjHi/f9tt5bodocEO0vBy6QYfblbLq3Hk7PhvAoAQXG7dmUFnGBdK87eDYGDcSQ7GP2ClTOVwb6YqgTBmWGgpIlJnQ4rDqKyaam26IPUWgbJXjmgBzLNCUWJZzQSWkFv3hU@wJ0IUFZsvPgXyHayvJb@2XlQi@kzbJKLqDX/lpnt8)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 110 bytes

Seems like PHP has some good built-in functions for this. I just array_sum the whole thing, then if there's more than two elements, subtract the min() and max() values and divide by 2 less than the length of the array.

For the rounding, I use the round() function with the PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN flag (which = 2) on double the average, and then divide it by 2 so it goes in increments of 0.5

EDIT: for the case of [6.5, 9] I'm following the stated rule that 7.75 rounds to 7.5 and not 8 like in the original example given.

```php
function s($s){$c=count($s);$t=array_sum($s);if($c>2){$c-=2;$t-=min($s)+max($s);}return round($t/$c*2,0,2)/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1RC4IwEAfw9z7FIXvQmhoDM7HVB6kIWYo@OMecUISffW0zoQd9Obj7/@5O1EKfLqIWG4CS1R30/vVwDyLvxr38fxYlGLKFIMOQYjgurWBIpnB504TTVSfStaeTsWVFzSZ15qdnp6uBM9V03EjUBx/EKOsGrmyTI0ULKYv3ox9aN2gqH7EzsSykxOQhbRtuo11bvBwZZakGyUGaK08fqRixLcF7TIKY5KPWXw)

Comment: Well done! I wanted to post a PHP answer but the rules had many flaws or changes that I just gave up! I tweaked your code a little and saved 10 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1RC4IwEAfw932KJXvYbGoszMSsD2ISshR9cI6pYESffenMh0Bf7uD@v7uTpdSXmywlAKiIddEL3lWNwKglb5V3vRJQNb14Ypwplb0ebV9PmZPUlUH7OhumniZoiI9XxGM@8s6MiIcRd3ZosBmxGT1QRjwWfXQEAIQ5LxuICpycUuJad2FFf0PXpzBcS0IKAwrPq0sU@nO6sTum82FDgs3HM5rKFltQYNCPL1B/AQ "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) `--force_float`, <s><sup>141</sup></s> <s><sup>136</sup></s> <s><sup>109</sup></s> 96 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RCoIwFIbvfYoDerGlpjPMMqdE1FUQRHdREVEUtCltwSp6dltJaYyx//@@w9ldHEuxl3khYTKbj8abyXQ2XBj5@caK0w7hh3Hl2sMWGHBQIEGUnFpkcMgvuiIkbaocRlXKMhUzh1OVcJ24I2jQQmYaZEi6zOXYQ6Yb4Fh6JsbYSJLEWiKx9m0kXP2k7TAjsY@xF6zK5/d/6NapHUL/1/oQQa92EL57w4fVvGbR34YP1bfJKxq9aWWbRh/iAyFAOuUL)
 <s><sub>[109bytes](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoIwFIbvfYoDebFlpjPMMqdE1FUQRHdRMaIoaDPaglX07DaTyhjbOf/3HQ67y0Mhdyo/K5jM5qPxZjKdDRdWfrrx83GL8MO6CuOBAQcBGhTIglObgCgfRu3GYJ9fjEBIOVS3ONUpz3TMW4LqRJhOYGxJai@DJmJpkCHlcldgDzE3wLHyGF4NkiSxl0iufQdJ15S0HWYk9jH2glXx/HwGur@uHUL/m/oQQe/nICxzzYfVvGHR34Y3NbfOKxqVtLJ1Yw7xgRAgneIF)</sub></s>
 <s><sub>[136bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5va8IwEIff51McWEoyqW0qtVr6Bxn2lSCMvZM4wnBMMKksGVTFz16vdqyVcLl7nt8RcjHfTXU8q9Phk7Ir@dVmb0GCAg01WDANcnWyUG7eXlcf5XqzfCcqczjo9pKZMyJf1Q/uUmrHWc2Y62K8rXNV1IkSrqtbSjWSFsQghC9U5mFBrac8zXwqvZAl1pdMkDRNnS01u2BMjYctn0QFTwLG/FA0N/L3T5j10ySCxT8tIIZ5n0HU8iCPun108dMLD4s19J2NW9ulwwQPD4Bz4NPmDg)</sub></s>
 <s><sub>[141bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5dS8MwFIbv8ysOrJRzHF2bjlpX@qHIdjUYiHejShBFwaRjiVAd@@31dJWtEpKT53lfQn7se9d8fuvdxwvSQXwZ@@pAgQYDLTiwHXOzc7DaPNwvn1frzd2j0IUnwfSHKryJeGv23EXvlhDdtGiJfJ8r27bUVZvp2vdNT7lhMrWwDPEVqjKu0AU6MBSiCmLKXKioFnmee1u0T9EUbcCjjGZJJbOIKIzr7ij@PgvXl9ssgcWZFpDCzSWDpOdRngx9dum/F06W99gPNu3tkI4TXjICKUHOu18)</sub></s>

```
n=$1;for x ((t+=x,m=x>m?x:m,n=x<n?x:n,s=2*(#>2?(t-m-n)/(#-2):t/#)))
<<<$[(s^0+(s-s^0>.5?1:0))/2]
```

Solution follows latest spec, except for the unclear second test case. Saved a few bytes using implicit `($@)`. Saved more by moving most calculations into the `(( ))` statement.

We implicitly iterate over the arguments with `for x`, and build a running total `t`, and also find maxima, minima `m, n`. If the number of arguments `#` is greater than 2, we discard `m` and `n` from the average. `s` is 2x the resulting average. If the mantissa of `s` is greater than 0.5, round `s` up, otherwise truncate with `s^0`. Finally, divide by 2 and output.